# D3.js d3.line giving unexpected results when taking values from an input

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3.js line chart that I want to update on user-input. One path is for ‘total price’, made up of a fixed price + a variable cost. I also show a ’fixed price’ line (not a path).

I have a slider to change the value of the fixed cost and then update the path and line.

The line takes the new inputted slider value and updates as expected. The path, however, starts being plotted with very negative y values and so doesn’t show on the chart.

Am I missing some logic to this?

If I hard-code a new value for ‘fixedCost’ the path updates as expected, but as soon as I substitute it for document.getElementById('fixed').value - it gives me a negative plot. The same problem occurs on first draw if I use the slider value.

I've successfully updated line charts in D3 before but that's usually loading new data set on a change event. I haven't encountered this problem with paths before. I'm using D3 V4. Below is the code for the slider and for the update function. Thanks

```
...javascript

var slider = d3.select("#chart").append("p").attr('id', 'slider')  
        .style('position', 'absolute')  
        .style('top', height + margin.top + 60 + 'px')  
        .style('left', margin.left + 'px')  
        .append("input")  
        .attr("type", "range")  
        .attr('id', 'fixed')  
        .attr("value", 408000)  
        .attr("min", 0)  
        .attr("max", 1000000)  
        .style("width", sliderWidth)  
        .on("input", updateFixed);  

// set starting parameters  

// var fixedCost = document.getElementById('fixed').value; // doesn't behave as expected when plotting path.  

var fixedCost = 408000;  

var valuelineTotCost = d3.line()  
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.subs); })  
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.variCost + fixedCost); });  


function updateFixed() {  

var thisValue = document.getElementById('fixed').value;  

d3.select('#sliderText')  
  .text("Fixed Costs: " + format(thisValue) );  // displays as expected

console.log(thisValue);  // returns as expected  

svg.select('#fixedCostLine')    
      .attr("x1", 0)  
      .attr("x2", width)  
      .attr("y1", y(thisValue))  
      .attr("y2", y(thisValue));  // this line updates as expected  

// var fixedCost = document.getElementById('fixed').value; // tried this instead of using thisValue but still not behaving as expected  

// var fixedCost = thisValue;  // also not behaving as expected

var fixedCost = 508000;  // behaves as expected

// adjust totCost path
var valuelineTotCost = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.subs); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.variCost + fixedCost); });

svg.select("#totalPath")
  .style("stroke", "purple")
  .attr("d", valuelineTotCost);

};
...
```

Here are the original path co-ordinates generated by d3.line followed by the negative y plots given when adjusted (even minutely) using the slider value.
Lastly, using a hard-coded value for the update, switching from the starting point of 408000 to 508000 - gave the third set of plots.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't post all those co-ordinates. Instead here are the first set of co-ordinates for each scenario above:   d="M0,294.3818181818182  ...  d="M0,-47726949.39771818 ...  d="M0,275.29090909090905

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path generator was reading the value from the input as a string.

thisValue = parseInt(thisValue);

solved the problem.